# PHP: "localhost redirected you too many times ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: php, mysql

I was making a inventory management system that if you logged in you will be redirected to the customer information.

**This is my code in Login page:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['KEY']))
{
header("location:datagrid_customer_info.php");
}
else
{

if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
    require_once("_config.php");

    $txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $txtPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];


    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM view_login_info WHERE cEmail    =:txtEmail AND cPassword =:txtPassword");
    $STH->bindparam(":txtEmail",$txtEmail);
    $STH->bindparam(":txtPassword",$txtPassword);
    $STH->execute();
    $ROW = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $CTR = $STH->rowCount();
        if($CTR==1){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['idLogin'] = $ROW['idLogin'];
            $_SESSION['KEY'] = 1;

            $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE adm_login_info SET cLock=0,  cLastLogin = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') WHERE idLogin=:idLogin");
            $STH->bindparam(":idLogin",$ROW['idLogin']);
            $STH->execute();

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Welcome to Inventory Management System');";
            echo "window.location.href='datagrid_customer_info.php';";
            echo "</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Login Error!');";
            echo "window.location.href='login.php';";
            echo "</script>";
        }   
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Inventory Management System Ver. 1</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body> 
<div style="width:22%;margin:60px auto;">
<form action="<?=htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post">
    <div id="panel_head"><img src="images/nav_icons/inv.png"   align="left">&nbsp;SYSTEM LOGIN</div>
    <div id="panel_body">
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%"    class="table_style">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>EMAIL</td>
                    <td><input type="text" required name="txtEmail"   size="25" autocomplete="off"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" required name="txtPassword"   size="25" autocomplete="off"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="panel_footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btnLogin">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

**My index code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['KEY'])==0)
{
header('location:datagrid_customer_info.php');
}
else
{
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

**My customer info page code:**

```
<?php
require_once("_config.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST['del_id']))
{

 $STH=$DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM inv_customer_info WHERE idCustomer=:id");
 $STH->bindparam(":id",$_REQUEST['id']);
 $STH->execute();
 header("Location:datagrid_customer_info.php");
 }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Customer Information</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRow(row)
{
    var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
}
function checkAll(ele) {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 if (ele.checked) {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = true;
         }
     }
 } else {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         console.log(i)
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = false;
         }
     }
 }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnDelete(clicked_id) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
    if (r == true) {
        window.location.href='datagrid_customer_info.php?del_id=';
    } else {
        window.location.href='index.php';
    }
}
function fnEdit(clicked_id){
window.location.href='edit_customer_info.php?id='+clicked_id;
}
function fnInsert(){
window.location.href='new_customer_info.php';
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="position:absolute; top:0px; margin:0px;">
<?php
include("top_navigation.php");
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<div style="width:75%;margin:60px auto;">
<div id="panel_head"><img src="images/customer.png"    
 align="left">&nbsp;CUSTOMER INFORMATION</div>
<div id="panel_body">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="98%"   
    id="myTable" class="table_style">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" 
            name="chk[]"></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th colspan="2">Customer</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Billing Address</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    //$start=0;
    //$limit=3;

    //$id=$_GET['id'];
    //$start=($id-1)* $limit;

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM view_customer_info ORDER BY 
    TransactDate DESC");
    $STH->execute();
    $CTR = $STH->rowCount();

     while($ROW = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if($ROW['fGender']=='Male'){
            $img_gender = "images/male.png";
        }else{
            $img_gender ="images/female.png";
        }
        if($ROW['New']==1){
            $new = "images/new.png";
        }else{
            $new = "images/old.png";
        }
        if($ROW['fStatus']=='Active'){
            $img_status = "images/active.png";
        }else{
            $img_status = "images/inactive.png";
        }
    ?>
        <tr class="row_style" onclick="selectRow">
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="<?
            =$ROW['idCustomer']?>"></td>
            <td align="center"><img src="<?=$new?>"></td>
            <td align="center"><?=$ROW['id']?></td>
            <td><img src="<?=$img_gender?>">&nbsp;<?=$ROW['fCustomerName']?>   
           </td>
            <td><?=$ROW['DOB']?></td>
            <td><?=$ROW['Age']?></td>
            <td><?=$ROW['Gender']?></td>
            <td><?=$ROW['cBillingAddress']?></td>
            <td><img src="<?=$img_status?>"></td>
            <td align="center" width="3%">
                <input type="button" onclick="fnEdit(this.id)" value="Edit"   
            id="<?=$ROW['idCustomer']?>">  
            </td>
            <td align="center" width="3%">
                <input type="button" onclick="fnDelete(this.id)"   
               value="Delete" id="<?=$ROW['idCustomer']?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="panel_footer">
    <input type="button" onclick="fnInsert(this.id)" value="Insert New">
    <input type="submit" name="cmdDelete" value="Delete Selected">
<?php
        require_once("_config.php");

        if(isset($_REQUEST['cmdDelete'])){
            if(isset($_REQUEST['cmdCheck'])){
                $checkbox = $_REQUEST['cmdCheck'];
                for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
                    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
                    $STH = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM inv_customer_info
                WHERE idCustomer=:del_id");
                    $STH->bindparam(":del_id",$del_id);
                    $STH->execute();
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
                    echo "alert('Successfully Deleted');";
                    echo      
                    "window.location.href='datagrid_customer_info.php';";
                    echo "</script>";
                }
            }
        }else{
            $checkbox = "";
        }
        ?>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I really do not know what is the problem here.I have already checked my cookies.

Comment: Could you specify what code goes with what php file?

Comment: What's going wrong? Is it just not working or doing something it shouldn't, are there any errors?

Comment: It does not redirect to the main page... @Addison

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be cause by an infinite redirect loop. I suggest it's here:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
     $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
     $STH = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM inv_customer_info WHERE idCustomer=:del_id");
     $STH->bindparam(":del_id",$del_id);
     $STH->execute();
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
     echo "alert('Successfully Deleted');";
     echo "window.location.href='datagrid_customer_info.php';";
     echo "</script>";
 }
```

You are redirecting in loop.

Also, using headers in php might be complicated, I suggest you use a refresh meta tag instead. You can use it in PHP like this:

```
<?php
$location = 'destination/file.php?variable=value';
echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$location.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Varaible? or Variable? What does that mean? @Ivan Venediktov

Comment: @Ajax variable, sorry.

Comment: @Ajax, it holds the value!